# How would I add concatenate items to a master dataframe that I receive from a requests.get()

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I have an api call that is returning the date and adjusted close prices for given tickers in a for loop.

There are 1100 unique tickers x 252 days, and I want to create a dataframe that's 1100x252 with the index as date.

The problem is that I can only query the api one ticker at a time, and it returns below (a sample of first several rows) which is for AAPL:

```
[{'date': '2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z', 'adjClose': 73.4677943274},
 {'date': '2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z', 'adjClose': 72.7535410914},
 {'date': '2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z', 'adjClose': 73.3332603275},
 {'date': '2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z', 'adjClose': 72.9883640731},
 {'date': '2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z', 'adjClose': 74.1624789816},
 {'date': '2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z', 'adjClose': 75.7377498172},
 {'date': '2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z', 'adjClose': 75.908974908}]
```

What I am trying to create is a loop that extracts the `adjClose`, and merges them to a master dataframe, of sorts.

I am currently looping through via:

```
tickers = list(data.ticker.unique)

for ticker in tickers:
    api_call = reqests.get(f'api_call_from_site.com/stonkz&ticker={tickers}')

    df = pd.DataFrame(api_call.json())
```

I then want to concatenate the `adjClose` from each specific api call to said "master dataframe," but I have no idea where to start. This would look like the below:

NOTE: values for AAPL (and other tickers) would resemble above.

```
date        AAPL    TSLA    AMD    NVDA    etc
2020-01-02  75      110     65     205     100
2020-01-03  76      111     66     206     101
2020-01-04  77      112     67     207     102
2020-01-05  78      113     68     208     103
2020-01-06  79      114     69     209     104
2020-01-07  80      115     70     210     105
2020-01-08  81      116     71     211     106
2020-01-09  82      117     72     212     107
2020-01-10  83      118     73     213     108
```

Any and all help is appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First idea is create list of `Series` by append and then join in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
L = []
for ticker in tickers:
    api_call = reqests.get(f'api_call_from_site.com/stonkz&ticker={ticker}')

    df = pd.DataFrame(api_call.json()).set_index('date')['adjClose'].rename(ticker)
    L.append(df)
    
df_big = pd.concat(L, axis=1)
```

Or create list of dictionaries `out` and last call `DataFrame` with transpose:

```
out = []
for ticker in tickers:
    api_call = reqests.get(f'api_call_from_site.com/stonkz&ticker={ticker}').json()
    d = {x['date']:x['adjClose'] for x in api_call}
    out.append(d)

df_big = pd.DataFrame(out, index=tickers).T
```